# How to remove all first articles from a string?

Tags: python, list, article

I have a list where i want to remove all first articles:
["the house", "the beautiful garten", "the beautiful garten of the house"]

and i want the list to only contain:
["house", "beautiful garten", "beautiful garten of the house"]

If the first word is an article, then remove. In case the articles appears in the sentence, they should be kept.

Comment: Is it always just `the ` you want to remove, or is there a list of articles (e.g. `['the', 'an', 'his']`)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with python try

```
new_list = [s[4:] if s.startswith('the ') else s for s in old_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `re` (this example will also ignore whitespaces around the first `the`:

```py
import re

lst = ["the house", "the beautiful garten", "the beautiful garten of the house"]

pat = re.compile(r"^\s*the\s+", flags=re.I)
out = [pat.sub("", w) for w in lst]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['house', 'beautiful garten', 'beautiful garten of the house']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of potential articles or words to be trimmed, you can do the following to remove that word plus the following space:

```
articles = ["the", "a", "an"]

sentences = ["the house", "a beautiful garten", "an amazing garten of the house"]


out = []
for s in sentences:
    new = s
    for a in articles:
      if s.startswith(f'{a} '):
        new = s[len(a)+1:]
    out.append(new)

print(out)

['house', 'beautiful garten', 'amazing garten of the house']
```